# Which Resharper Setting controls alignment of Lambdas

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I have this code

```
ToggleAnalyzeCmd = new DelegateCommand(
       () =>
       {
           if (IsAnalyzing)
               CancelAnalysis();
           else
               Analyze(false);
       },
       () => IsAnalyzing)
   .ObservesProperty(() => IsAnalyzing);
```

But when I type it or reformat it with Resharper (version 2022.3.1), it really wants those two lambdas to be lined up right under the `DelegateCommand`  No matter how far to the right that is.  Here is what I get if I select the block of code and use Resharper's "FormatCode" command

```
ToggleAnalyzeCmd = new DelegateCommand(
                       () =>
                       {
                           if (IsAnalyzing)
                               CancelAnalysis();
                           else
                               Analyze(false);
                       },
                       () => IsAnalyzing)
                   .ObservesProperty(() => IsAnalyzing);
```

Looking at *Options >> Code Editing >> C# >> Tabs, Indents, Alignment,* I am trying to find what setting controls this

I tried checking/unchecking the most obvious candidate; This setting:

```
Align multiline constructs >> Anonymous Method Body
```

It has no effect.  My code still gets indented regardless.    I don't see any other setting that looks like it could.

Anyone know what setting I am looking for?

EDIT: By request I am sharing my resharper settings file - just the code editing and code-style properties.  This is long though

```
<wpf:ResourceDictionary xml:space="preserve" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:ss="urn:shemas-jetbrains-com:settings-storage-xaml" xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeEditing/GenerateMemberBody/MethodImplementationKind/@EntryValue">ReturnDefaultValue</s:String>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeEditing/GenerateMemberBody/WrapIntoRegions/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeEditing/Intellisense/CodeCompletion/AutoCompleteSmartCompletion/@EntryValue">False</s:Boolean>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeEditing/Intellisense/CodeCompletion/EditorBrowsableProcessing/@EntryValue">Advanced</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeEditing/Intellisense/CodeCompletion/ParenthesesInsertType/@EntryValue">Left</s:String>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeEditing/Intellisense/CodeCompletion/ReplaceKeywordsWithTemplates/@EntryValue">False</s:Boolean>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeEditing/Intellisense/CodeCompletion/IntelliSenseCompletingCharacters/NonCompletingCharacters/@EntryValue">.,;</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeEditing/Intellisense/CodeCompletion/IntelliSenseCompletingCharacters/CSharpCompletingCharacters/NonCompletingCharacters/@EntryValue">.,;</s:String>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeEditing/Intellisense/CodeCompletion/IntelliSenseCompletingCharacters/CSharpCompletingCharacters/UpgradedFromVSSettings/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeEditing/Intellisense/LookupWindow/ShowAnnotations/@EntryValue">All</s:String>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeEditing/Intellisense/LookupWindow/UseCompletionFontForLookups/@EntryValue">False</s:Boolean>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeEditing/TypingAssist/BraceInsertType/@EntryValue">DISABLED</s:String>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeEditing/TypingAssist/InsertAsteriskInBlockComments/@EntryValue">False</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeEditing/TypingAssist/SkipClosingBracesOnTabInIndentPosition/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeEditing/TypingAssist/SkipClosingBracesOnTabInStringLiterals/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeEditing/TypingAssist/SmartBackspace/@EntryValue">OFF</s:String>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeEditing/TypingAssist/SurroundTypingEnabled/@EntryValue">False</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/ALIGN_LINQ_QUERY/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/ALIGN_MULTILINE_BINARY_PATTERNS/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/ALIGN_MULTILINE_CALLS_CHAIN/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/ALIGN_MULTILINE_EXTENDS_LIST/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/ALIGN_MULTILINE_FOR_STMT/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/ALIGN_MULTILINE_PARAMETER/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/ALIGN_MULTILINE_STATEMENT_CONDITIONS/@EntryValue">False</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/ALIGN_MULTIPLE_DECLARATION/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/ALIGN_MULTLINE_TYPE_PARAMETER_CONSTRAINS/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/ALIGN_MULTLINE_TYPE_PARAMETER_LIST/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/ALIGN_TUPLE_COMPONENTS/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/ALLOW_FAR_ALIGNMENT/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INDENT_BRACES_INSIDE_STATEMENT_CONDITIONS/@EntryValue">False</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INDENT_CASE_FROM_SWITCH/@EntryValue">False</s:Boolean>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INDENT_INVOCATION_PARS/@EntryValue">OUTSIDE</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INDENT_METHOD_DECL_PARS/@EntryValue">OUTSIDE</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INDENT_PARS/@EntryValue">OUTSIDE</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INDENT_STATEMENT_PARS/@EntryValue">OUTSIDE</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INDENT_TYPEARG_ANGLES/@EntryValue">OUTSIDE</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INDENT_TYPEPARAM_ANGLES/@EntryValue">OUTSIDE</s:String>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INT_ALIGN_ASSIGNMENTS/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INT_ALIGN_BINARY_EXPRESSIONS/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INT_ALIGN_COMMENTS/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INT_ALIGN_FIELDS/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INT_ALIGN_INVOCATIONS/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INT_ALIGN_METHODS/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INT_ALIGN_NESTED_TERNARY/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INT_ALIGN_PARAMETERS/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INT_ALIGN_PROPERTIES/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INT_ALIGN_PROPERTY_PATTERNS/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INT_ALIGN_SWITCH_SECTIONS/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/INT_ALIGN_VARIABLES/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/KEEP_EXISTING_DECLARATION_BLOCK_ARRANGEMENT/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/OUTDENT_COMMAS/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/PLACE_ABSTRACT_ACCESSORHOLDER_ON_SINGLE_LINE/@EntryValue">False</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/STICK_COMMENT/@EntryValue">False</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/USE_INDENT_FROM_VS/@EntryValue">False</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/WRAP_AFTER_DECLARATION_LPAR/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Int64 x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/WRAP_LIMIT/@EntryValue">165</s:Int64>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/Generate/=Implementations/@KeyIndexDefined">True</s:Boolean>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/Generate/=Implementations/Options/=Mutable/@EntryIndexedValue">False</s:String>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/Naming/CSharpAutoNaming/IsNotificationDisabled/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean></wpf:ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this in Rider. Could you please share your R# settings file?

Comment: I cannot attach files so I added the code editing and code style settings on to the end of my post

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with Rider, so it must be really related to R# in VS

Comment: I appreciate the effort!